# Which software/s to create a video like this - 3d explainer video

Tags: video, after-effects, 3d, blender

I'm trying to create a 3d animated video link this

https://www.veed.io/view/b19fbccb-2f97-405e-bb64-3d8ffc5e9401?sharingWidget=true&panel=share

I've researched and found the following:
Blender: Can be used for 3d modelling but it's more geared towards artists to create 3d artwork.
Solidworks: Parametric design software used for manufacturing.

I did like what I saw in solidworks but found out it's to model products and used mostly for manufacturing.

I understand there could be multiple softwares (like After Effects, Premier Pro) involved in making a video like this but I'm starting now and want to make a videos like these 6 months to 1 year for now. I don't want to learn a tool only to realise I need to learn something else.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This could definitely be made using Blender. The text and lines could have been added using After Effects afterwards (Blender can do this too), but the 3D modelling would all be rendered in a 3D tool like Blender.

It's free, you should give it a go.  Start by [building a donut](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nIoXOplUvAw&list=PLjEaoINr3zgFX8ZsChQVQsuDSjEqdWMAD&index=1&ab_channel=BlenderGuru) - it's a great set of free tutorials.

Answer (score 1):

I think also that Blender is the best for making similar explainer videos. This will be the best universal DIY solution in view of the ease of learning and the budget. You can, of course, try, for example, Autodesk Maya or Unity. These are also reletively not very complex tools enabling you create similar 3D models. The question may be the price and time to get used to them.
Depending on how much detailed modeling is required and what skills you have, a similar task can be implemented with one of the [Best 3D Modeling Software](https://www.g2.com/categories/3d-modeling) list.  You need to try and experiment. This will take time. Although, there are options, when refining the task.
If I understood the question correctly, the task for the next 6-12 months is to create several videos explaining the assembly of certain objects, without specifying their technical characteristics, but giving a visual representation of the process and sequence. At the same time, the budget is limited and by the end of the project there are no plans to create any more videos in the future. Right?
Under such task conditions, I think it worth to get understanding of the [animation pipeline](https://bluecarrot.io/blog/how-to-create-an-animation-pipeline-pre-amp-post-production-process/) in order to choose the optimal solution for such tasks. After all, 3D modeling is still a skill that needs to be mastered. What is not included in your plans for the future, as I understand it, right?
Then, with a limited budget, you can simplify the decision, how to choose a different type of animation with ready-made templates and any other [explainer video software](https://www.webdew.com/blog/explainer-video-software). Or save time by ordering ready reels from those who understand the processes of creating such videos.
Well, if, nevertheless, you want to DIY, then I would recommend proceeding from what you already know and can do. If you are already familiar with the blender, then try to do the maximum with it and look at the materials recommended above by Tomh